# How us the policy based routing using dual wan single lan in cisco for below scenario

Tags: cisco-ios

How us the policy based routing in cisco for below scenario :

```
Wan 1 : 

  ip address : 10.10.10.2 
  subnetmask : 255.255.255.252
  gateway    : 10.10.10.1
```

Wan 2  :

```
  ip address : 20.20.20.2 
  subnetmask : 255.255.255.252
  gateway    : 20.20.20.1
```

Lan :

```
  ip address : 172.168.0.4 
  subnetmask : 255.255.240.0
```

I want to allow the wan 10.10.10.2 for 172.168.0.10, 172.168.0.11, 172.168.0.12

and

I want to allow the wan 20.20.20.2 for 172.168.0.13, 172.168.0.14, 172.168.0.15

with using access list

Please help me complete this

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that: for example for interface with IP 172.168.0.13

Create access list to tell PBR to not inclue traffic to internal network (you can use it for all PBR or you can specify your own depend on your needs)

> ip access-list extended ACL_FOR_PBR
>   deny ip any   172.168.0.0    0.0.255.255
>   permit ip any any

next create the Policy Based Routing rule #1 :

> route-map PBR_RULE_13 permit 1 
>   match ip address ACL_FOR_PBR
>   set ip next-hop 20.20.20.2

next apply rule to the interface

> interface Fa0/13 
>   ip policy route-map PBR_RULE_13

Do the same for other interfaces.